# Trouble completing a function in mySQL

Tags: mysql, function, join

When I work on functions I like to test a stand-alone select statement first. I did that and it worked out. My problem is when I try to convert it into a function.

This is the select statement and it works

```
select sum(item.retailPrice * orderItem.quantity)
from orderItem
join orders 
on orders.orderId = orderItem.orderId
join item
on item.itemId = orderItem.itemId
where orders.orderId = 4
```

This is my function and it gives errors.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTotalPrice(oId int) 
RETURNS int
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
declare total int;
select sum(item.retailPrice * orderItem.quantity) into total
from orderItem
join orders 
on orders.orderId = orderItem.orderId
join item
on item.itemId = orderItem.itemId
where orders.orderId = oId
return total;
END$$
```

The function should allow the user to input their orderId.

Comment: short answer is that you really shouldn't bother writing functions for these simple queries.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the line above `RETURN`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SELECT INTO to select into a variable, you need to use the @ sign to preface those variables.  Unfortunately [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) isn't responding right now so I can validate this suggestion but I recommend trying changing these two lines:

```
select sum(item.retailPrice * orderItem.quantity) into total
...
return total;
```

To this:

```
select sum(item.retailPrice * orderItem.quantity) into @total
...
return @total;
```

Good luck!